# Pyside QTreeWidget with custom widget items disappear on drop

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyside, qtreewidget

I am tyring to put together a QTreeWidget UI that uses custom widgets as its items. I want to be able to drag and drop to rearrange the items in the tree. I am finding that, on drop, the custom widgets are getting lost. How can I make this work? Thanks.

Simplified code example below:

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class CustomWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, label_text, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidgetItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(label_text)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Custom Button")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def btn_click(self):
        print(self.label.text())

class CustomTreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QTreeView.InternalMove)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        source = event.source()
        if isinstance(source, QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
            super().dropEvent(event)
        else:
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            event.accept()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Custom Tree Widget")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tree_widget = CustomTreeWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tree_widget)
        self.add_items()

    def add_items(self):
        for i in range(5):
            child_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree_widget, ['Group %d' % i])
            custom_widget_item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(child_item)
            custom_widget = CustomWidgetItem('Item %d' % i)
            # set widget
            self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(custom_widget_item, 0, custom_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I cannot mark it as a duplicate as the OP didn't care to check my answer, but see [Drag and Drop a Widget in QTreeWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72741848). Long story short: you can't. That's not the purpose of index widgets, which are **always** destroyed whenever the index they belong to is removed (which also happens when trying to *move* indexes with drag&drop). Besides what's suggested in my answer, you could (and probably should) consider using an item delegate with a custom editor and then "reopen" the custom editor on drop actions.

Comment: By "index widgets", musicamante means you called "setItemWidget()". I don't recommend the tricky and complex implementation of his answer in the above link. As he noted at the end of his answer, you should implement a delegate and editor widget. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322993/how-to-implement-buttons-in-a-delegate-pyqt) for example. There are many good answers of musicamante related to this topic in SO. Check them.

Comment: @relent95 Thanks for the appreciation! :-) You're right, I should've been more specific: `setItemWidget()` of low-level classes such as QTreeWidget, QTableWidget and QListWidget, internally calls the base `QAbstractItemView.setIndexWidget()`. And, you're right again saying that it's not recommended (which, coincidentally, doesn't mean that it's actually "wrong"): the "Qt way" may not be optimal from the developer POV, but it's conceptually right considering performance and API consistency; "widget items", as also pointed in the docs, are not intended for those purposes: delegates are.

Comment: @musicamante Actually, drag and drop with item-widgets works fine for QListWidget (except for [one bug, that has now been fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-100128)). So, in principle, there's no reason why this shouldn't work for QTreeWidget: it's just another bug/limitation that hasn't been fixed yet. Really, it's totally unacceptable that the tree-widget should take ownership and then fail to manage the items properly. At the very least, the documentation should include a clear warning about this issue (or the implementation should actively disable drag and drop for item-widgets).

Comment: Thanks musicamante for pointing me towards your response in another thread. I had not seen that. As ekhumoro says, it seems like quite a complicated workaround considering something similar works nicely with a QListWidget.

Comment: @ekhumoro You're conceptually right, but I find that the real "inconsistency" is from QListView alone, as it's the only view that actually implements `dropEvent()` and tries to call `moveRow()`, which is implemented in the private model of QListWidget. This is possible because, by its nature, the list model can easily move items using `moveRows()`: there is just one dimension; but that's not possible with models that have more than one dimension (tables and trees) because Qt doesn't provide a way to "move" individual indexes: you can only move full rows or columns, and within the same parent.

Comment: @ekhumoro I completely agree with you: the docs should warn about that aspect (I don't remember if the Model/View page mentions it). Still, the point remains: "moving" individual indexes that could be part of a row *and* a column is not possible, so the only way that the +1D views have to "move" indexes is to "take" the dragged item and set it to the new index, something that *must* automatically reparent that item/index in some way (QTableWidget and QTreeWidget use `takeItem()` and `setItem()` in `dropEvent()`), and will unfortunately result in the index widget destruction as a consequence.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I understand the problem, but you have to consider that tree models are actually much more complex than an basic list. As explained in the above reply to ekhumoro, Qt does not provide a way to "move" individual indexes: you can only move full rows or columns. What makes it possible for QListWidget to do that is that it uses a 1 dimension model: moving an index is the same as moving a row, and within the same parent, so you *can* just move a single index: there's only one column, so you can move the "whole" row. That is not possible for table or tree models, because, in order to ->

Comment: @ChrisHawkes -> do that, the only thing that can be done is to insert the dragged item into a new row/column (possibly, of another parent) after removing its current row/column; the last part is what results in destroying the item widget. So, while I agree with you that my "workaround" may seem complicated, creating a new editor is the only available option. The only solution would be to ask Qt developers to provide a way to reparent index editors in order to avoid their destruction, allowing us to reimplement `dropEvent()` and eventually update the "new" indexes with the previous editors.

Comment: @musicamante I was careful to say "in principle". I'm obviously not arguing for *the current implementation*, since it clearly doesn't always work (which is also why I say drag and drop should be explicitly disabled for index-widgets in such cases). The real problem here would be persuading the Qt devs to implement a new architecture. AFAICS, there's never been a feature request on the bug tracker, so maybe it just isn't considered to be of any great importance (and the request would probably be immediately shot down anyway, since item-delegates are usually a much more efficient solution).